# What is the integrand of a path integral?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I have been reading the Deligne et. al notes "Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course For Mathematicians" and I am trying to reconcile what I learned with what physicists are doing. I am confused about what physicists mean by expressions of the form $$\langle 0|\phi(x_1)...\phi(x_n)|0\rangle= \int \mathcal{D}\phi \; \phi(x_1)...\phi(x_n)e^{iS[\phi]}$$
I am not asking about the measure $\mathcal{D}\phi$. This integral is supposed to be the "$n$-point correlation function of the field $\phi$" and should return a scalar, but the $\phi(x_i)$ are all supposed to be operators on a Hilbert space, so it is not clear to me how this happens.

This notation also suggests to me that this correlation function is independent of the field $\phi$ (since $\phi$ is also used for the variable of integration), but this seems unreasonable. Would it be correct to say $$\langle 0|\psi(x_1)...\psi(x_n)|0\rangle= \int \mathcal{D}\phi \; \psi(x_1)...\psi(x_n)e^{iS[\phi]}$$ instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field $\phi$ has slightly different meanings inside the path integral and outside of it, as the Feynman path integral is relating two different interpretations.

*Inside* the path integral, imagine that we're summing an action of *classical* fields over a measure of all possible values for those classical fields. As a variable of integration, $\phi$ is thus a classical field and each value $\phi(x_i)$ is a scalar value.

*Outside* the path integral is where $\phi$ is a Hilbert space operator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How does this work when the classical fields are not scalar fields? The example on my mind right now is $U(1)$ Yang-Mills theory; I am not aware of a natural way to multiply connections.

Comment: The action term S is always a scalar, and so the fields always have to be combined to form scalars. It's been a while since grad school, but memory serves that a U(1) Yang-Mills theory is just a complex scalar field $\psi$, and so the action involves terms like $\psi \psi^*$. For a non-abelian Yang-Mills theory, the representations of the fields always are combined to form scalars; e.g. using the metric if they are vector representations.

Comment: Coupling terms between different fields also have to combine to form scalars. For instance, the connection couples a vector representation of a gauge field with spinor representations of charged particle fields in Lagrangian like $\psi^\dagger \gamma^{\mu} D_{\mu} \psi$ which are scalar

Comment: sorry, I am not very familiar with the physics language for these things. My understanding is that a $U(1)$ gauge field is a connection $\mathcal{A}$ on the trivial $U(1)$-principal bundle $P$ over spacetime. I know the action is always scalar valued, but I am confused about the meaning of an expression like $\mathcal{A}(x_1)\mathcal{A}(x_2)e^{iS[\mathcal{A}]}$, where $x_1,x_2$ are points on spacetime.

Comment: I deleted my last comment because it was wrong (or at least misleading). An expectation like $\langle 0 \left| A\mu(x_1) A_\nu(x_2) \right| 0 \rangle$ is valid, where $A$ is the gauge field itself, a vector-valued operator on Hilbert space, and not the connection. Since the product of the vectors transforms like a tensor, this expectation transforms like a tensor valued. Now, the connection (which you've represented with $\mathcal{A}$) is formed from the gauge field(s) and the derivative operator, and this doesn't have a product operator that you could stick in a vacuum estimate.

Comment: You don't need to define an abstract product of connections. Just express things in coordinates and pick values for the indices attached to the connections then just take the product of the corresponding components or coordinates.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, am I right that in expectation values, correlation functions, etc. one only ever takes the gauge field part of the connection, and not the operator that  includes the term $i \gamma^2 \partial_\mu$? I guess the operator $\partial_\mu$ can be applied to the vacuum, as in Fourier space it would just be giving the momentum of the vacuum, and so maybe there's no reason in principle that the "full" connection couldn't appear as an Hamiltonian-picture operator. But since there's just one such connection even when there are multiple gauge fields, this didn't strike me as normal

Answer (score 2):

The integrand is the functional $F[\phi]:= \phi(x_1)\cdots\phi(x_n)\exp(iS[\phi])$. Your confusion probably stems from the fact that physicists like to jump around between the Hamiltonian picture where your field is some kind of operator-valued distribution, and the Feynman picture where you're working with path integrals and $\phi$ is just a function (or distribution). The link between them is precisely that the vacuum expectation value of the operator $\phi(x_1)\cdots\phi(x_n)$, i.e.
$$
\langle 0|\phi(x_1)\cdots\phi(x_n)|0\rangle,
$$ can be calculated as the path integral of the integrand I wrote above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How does this work when the classical fields are not scalar fields? The example on my mind right now is $U(1)$ Yang-Mills theory; I am not aware of a natural way to multiply connections.

Comment: Neither am I, lol. Ok, usually if your field classically is of type X (be that a section of a vector bundle, a differential form, or a connection on a principal bundle), you think of your operators as being some "operator version" of X, no idea what that means concretely :D
To your specific question: when you work with a gauge theory, you can only expect to get a nonzero expectation value if your expression is gauge-invariant, and I don't think products of the connection form are usually gauge-invariant.